# Find the solution of Diferential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question is following:

$\frac {dx}{dt}= y$

$\frac {dy}{dt}= 7x-8y+t$
with initial conditions $x(0)=-3,y(0)=11$

**Things I tried:** First thing that come to my mind is rewrite equations as

$dx=y.dt$ and $dy = (7x-8y+t)dt$
For the first equation: take integration both sides then we have $x= yt+c_1$ and the for other again take integration then $y=7xt-8yt+\frac{t^2}{2}+c_2$

Finally, applying initial condition then from first equation we get $x(0)=-3=y(0).0+c_1 \implies c_1=-3$. Further $c_2=11$

Is that correct? Is there any something wrong in my opinion that I approach to question?

Comment: Unfortunately not correct.

Comment: what should I need to do?

Comment: The system matrix $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 7 & -8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ has the eigenvalues $\left\{-\sqrt{23}-4,\sqrt{23}-4\right\}$.

Hence the solution is a combination of $e^{(-\sqrt{23}-4)t}$ and $e^{(\sqrt{23}-4)t}$ and also is unstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t$, which means you can't directly integrate both sides with respect to $t$. Usually, for a $2\times 2$ system of ODEs, you could either use the eigenvalue method or rewrite the system as a single second-order ODE with dependent variable $x$ or $y$. Let me do the second method instead, I chose to do it this way because I'm not sure if you have seen the eigenvalue method, otherwise the eigenvalue method is usually more efficient (in my opinion).

Ok, let me use primes to denote derivatives. Differentiating $x' = y$ with respect to $t$ gives $x'' = y'$. Substituting $y' = 7x - 8y + t = 7x - 8x' + t$ into this, we get
$$ x'' = 7x - 8x' + t, \ \ \textrm{ or } \ \ x'' + 8x' - 7x = t. $$
This is a second-order nonhomogeneous linear ODE. One can show (by finding the complementary and particular solution separately) that the general solution is given by
$$ x(t) = c_1e^{\left(-4 + \sqrt{23}\right)t} + c_2e^{\left(-4 - \sqrt{23}\right)t} - \frac{t}{7} - \frac{8}{49}. $$
I will let you complete the problem by finding the two constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ with initial conditions $x(0) = -3$ and $y(0) = x'(0) = 11$.